# Auto-populate calendar with an "X" in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have have a set of due dates for preventative maintenance on equipment and I want a calendar to auto-populate with an "X" under the correct month it is due.

For example I have machine 1 due 1/1.  I wan an "X" under the month January.  Machine 2 is due 6/15.  I want an "X" under June.  How can I translate the month of a date to a calendar cell location to accomplish this?

Comment: your question is too broad now, please share some sample data with us to help understanding how your information is organized.

Comment: In Tab 1 I have a set off machines and due dates.  For example, Machine 1 is due April 15th. I want an X to auto populate under the month it is due.  So an X would auto populate under April . If machine 2 is due December 3rd then I want an X to auto populate under December.  It would be a yearly schedule.

Comment: I tried using =if(A1,<>)A2=x.  I know this is not the correct way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

[image: screenshot]

Machine IDs and due dates are in columns A and B.  You can put the calendar where you want; I started it in D1.  The formula bases the month number on the column the calendar month is in.  In this example, January is in the 4th column so I subtract 3 from the column number to get the month number that the column represents.

The formula compares that to the month of the due date.  If they match, the cell gets an "X", otherwise a blank.  The formula in D2 is:

```
=IF(COLUMN()-3=MONTH($B2),"X","")
```

You can copy or drag that across and down as needed to populate the other calendar cells.